# How can I fix invalid parameter errors in puppet manifests?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I've got a seemingly impossible error in a very simple puppet manifest. I'm simply trying to use the example42 puppet-puppet module to run puppetmaster (with puppet 3.1.0). This is my site.pp:

```
node 'se2' { 
    class { 'puppet::server' :
        mode => 'server' }    
}
Exec { path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin" }
node default { }
```

With this, I get the error:

```
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/last_run.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppi_projects.rb
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid parameter mode at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:7 on node se2
```

(line 7 is the line with mode)

There must be something stupid I'm doing, from what I can see here, mode IS a valid parameter:

https://github.com/example42/puppet-puppet/blob/master/manifests/init.pp#L320

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing server.pp by calling
`puppet::server`

See this class for puppet::server
https://github.com/example42/puppet-puppet/blob/master/manifests/server.pp

To reference the class with parameter 'mode', use puppet.pp:

```
node 'se2' { 
  class { 'puppet' :
    mode => 'server',
  }    
}
Exec { path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin" }
node default { }
```

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding how inherit works in this case. Does the line:  

    class puppet::server inherits puppet

Not also pull in the parameterization directives from the puppet class? Being new to puppet, I'd think that it does the OOP thing and makes puppet::server do everything puppet can do.

Comment: Hey, sorry I missed this notification. `class puppet::server inherits puppet` does not pull in the parameterization directives. Instead, it acts as an include while also allowing resource overrides. For example, you could override the puppet.conf resource like so: 
`File[ 'puppet.conf'] { path => '/someotherpath', }`
If you do want to access parameters from another class, you can accomplish this through namespacing. `$::puppet::mode` would give you the puppet class mode parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Near the bottom of that page is this:

```
### PuppetMaster configuration
if $puppet::mode == 'server' {
  include puppet::server
}
```

But your class is already `puppet::server`.  I'm not overly familiar with writing providers but a class including itself doesn't seem likely to work.  Can you try making your class have a different name?

Comment: Not for this specific module, according to the linked source code.

Comment: @SvenW Ah, my mistake.  I didn't really read that page, only one part of it.  I think I may see the problem now.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a class called puppet::server, I'm simply trying to pull in the one from that module. The baby steps in puppet are super difficult :/

Comment: Indeed.  Good luck with it.  All I can at this point is "It's not just you."